# Where should I init a custom class in a viewcontroller in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best practice and how would I use it in a method? I have an init method in my object's class already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where should I init a custom class in a viewcontroller in Objective-C?

you should initialize your variables or custom class object in `viewDidLoad` or  in the `initWithNibName` method

> how to use?

you could initialize the custom class object like this

```
CustomClass *classObj = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
```

> how to use the custom class as property?

in **MyViewController.h**

```
@class CustomClass;

@interface MyViewController:ViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic)CustomClass *classObject;
```

in **MyViewController.m**

```
    #import "CustomClass.h"
......
    @synthesize classObject;
.....
    self.classObject=[[CustomClass alloc]init];
```

Comment: If I initialize it inside viewDidLoad how would I use it outside that method? What if I wanted to have classObj as a property?

Comment: you could declare it as a property and use in all the viewController

Comment: What would the code look like if I declared it as a property? Where would I init it then?

Comment: Got it, I forgot to use self to access the setter. I was simply using the variable name. Thanks

Comment: Is the synthesize necessary? Even though I don't implement the getter or setter myself?